# Best way of setting up dummy variables in multiple regression model?

Tags: regression, categorical-encoding

I have a regression model in which the independent variable correspends to a signal over time. If at a certain point in time a specific event occured, I introduced a dummy variable into the model containing only zeros except a $1$ at the time the event occured. So suppose this happened 30 times, is there a difference between the way I did it (introducing 30 separate dummy variables, each with a single $1$) and introducing only one dummy variable which would then contain 30 ones, regarding the estimated effect of the other independent variables (which are not correlated with the dummy variables)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a better answer you need to tell us more details, like your modeling goal. But, you ask about comparing two methods:

1. One indicator variable  with a 1 for each of 30 events, or
2. 30 indicator variables each with only one 1 for 1 event.

You must use alternative 1. The second alternative, with variables with only one 1, the effect us to fit 30 parameters which only represents one event each, and so will be fitted perfectly. That way you will not learn anything generalize-able!